# Why a programmer would prefer O(N^3) instead of O(N^2)

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o, time-complexity

I was studying for my final exam and there is a question in the archive that I cannot find its answer:

> The order-of-growth of the running time of one algorithm is O(N^2); the
>   order-of-growth of the running time of a second algorithm is O(N^3). List
>   three compelling (logical, convincing) reasons why a programmer would
>   prefer to use the O(N^3) algorithm instead of the O(N^2) one.

Comment: Divide `100000 / 10` in your head. Now do it using long division on paper. Which was faster? Divide `21714 / 66` in your head. Now do it using long division on paper. Which was faster? The fastest method depends on your input. The first example was like `O(n^3)`. But it works well for nice numbers. The second example was like `O(n^2)`. It has better performance in general, but you don't want to bring it out to do a simple division.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I can think of the following three reasons:

- Ease of initial implementation.
- Ease of maintenance in the future.
- The O(N^3) algorithm may have a lower space complexity than the O(N^2) algorithm (i.e., it uses less memory).

Comment: 4. n is small (so it doesn't really matter)

Comment: @DSM That is only a good reason if the size is small enough for the constants to dominate, and thus covered by #4.

Comment: @delnan: #4 is a prerequisite (for the appropriate sense of 'small'), but #4 doesn't cover it.  Doesn't matter, though, as two separate answers now hit the same point.

Answer (score 22):

Probably the #1 reason: because the O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm has enough higher constants that for the size of task being contemplated, the O(N<sup>3</sup>) version is faster.

Answer (score 12):

Here is are examples to convince you that O(N³) can be in some cases better than O(N²).

> 1. O(N²) algorithm is very complex to code whereas if input size is say N ≤ 100 then for practical use O(N³) can be fast enough
> 2. O(N²) has a large constant multiplied to it for example c = 1000 hence for N = 100, c⋅N² = 1000⋅100² = 10⁷ whereas if c = 1 for
>      O(N³) then c⋅N³ = 10⁶
> 3. O(N²) algorithm has very high space complexity as compared to O(N³)

Comment: That's not an example.

Answer (score 4):

another thing is, some algorithms have a big constant factor.
a `O (N^2)` might have a big constant factor that won't make it really practical to use ( if `N` is small enough as kindly noted by Thorban)

Comment: if the input n is sufficiently small

Answer (score 2):

The only reason for choosing one algorithm is not the order-of-growth of the running time. You must analyze:

- How easy it is to implement
- The space required
- How big are the real life inputs (sometimes the time difference is only observable for input sizes that never occurs in reality)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the already posted answers I'd like to mention cache behaviour. A particular memory access pattern might be so much slower due to repeated cache misses that a theoretically slower algorithm with a more cache friendly memory access pattern performs much better.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O is an upper bound on the worst case. QuickSort is O(n^2) time and MergeSort is O(n lgn) time. But people use QuickSort because on average it is O(n lgn) with lower constants than MergseSort.